# asp.net + EventName for UpdatePanel textbox onblur event

Tags: asp.net

I have added an onblur attribute to a textbox, what should put as the EventName for my UpdatePanel? I tried onblur but it gave me an error:

'Could not find an event named 'onblur' on associated control 'uitxtCamCode' for the trigger in UpdatePanel 'UpdatePanel2'.'

Please kindly advice. Thanks.

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                        <Triggers>
                            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="uitxtCamCode" EventName="onblur" />
                        </Triggers>
                        <ContentTemplate>

                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="uilblCamCode" Text="<%$ Resources:loyaltyManagerResources, uilblCamCode %>"
                            CssClass="label">
                        </asp:Label>

                        <asp:TextBox ID="uitxtCamCode" runat="server" CssClass="tooltip" Width="150px"></asp:TextBox>

                        </ContentTemplate>
                        </asp:UpdatePanel>


  Protected Sub Page_Init(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Init

        Dim onBlurScript = Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(uitxtCamCode, "OnBlur")
        uitxtCamCode.Attributes.Add("onblur", onBlurScript)

    End Sub



  Private Sub HandleCustomPostbackEvent(ByVal ctrlName As String, ByVal args As String)

    CheckAvailability()

    If lblCCodeAvailability.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Red And uitxtCamCode.Text <> "" Then
        If (ctrlName = uitxtCamCode.UniqueID And args = "OnBlur") Then
        End If
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a *Javascript* event handler.
It cannot have anything to do with an `UpdatePanel`.

Comment: So which means there's not way to use an UpdatePanel for this situation?

Comment: That doesn't make sense.  UpdatePanels are for server-side code; `onblur` is client-side code.